# Infinite loop in CURSOR

Tags: t-sql, cursors

I'm trying to use a cursor to clean up temp tables when they are no longer needed. I have a small table which has the names of the temp tables along with an identifier. The cursor is stuck in an infinite loop, but only if I execute certain statements in it. If I just print out the values from the `FETCH`, it works perfectly. Here is the code.

```
DECLARE @id bigint;
DECLARE @table_name varchar(max);

DECLARE st CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR 
SELECT ID, TableName FROM SearchTables WHERE CustomerID IS NULL

OPEN st
FETCH NEXT FROM st INTO @id, @table_name
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS <> -1 
BEGIN   
    IF(OBJECT_ID(@table_name) IS NOT NULL) 
        EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @table_name);

    UPDATE SearchTables SET Deleted=1 WHERE ID=@id;

    PRINT CAST(@id AS varchar(max)) + ' ' + @table_name;

    FETCH NEXT FROM st INTO @id, @table_name;
END 

CLOSE st
DEALLOCATE st
```

If I comment out these lines

```
    IF(OBJECT_ID(@table_name) IS NOT NULL) 
        EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @table_name);

    UPDATE SearchTables SET Deleted=1 WHERE ID=@id;
```

`PRINT` outputs all of the IDs and table names. If I don't comment them, all I get is the first row over and over until I cancel the query. I also tried changing the `IF` line to `EXEC('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ' + @table_name)` but that didn't work either.

Comment: I wonder why you did have a need to clean up the temp tables? Even it's local or global temp table, it's alive within a user transaction, and will be dropped automatically. I'm not sure for your case, so?

Comment: @DatNguyen I am not using local or global temp tables, I am using "permanent" temp tables. Which don't get dropped until tempdb is restarted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably you're moving the row when you set `Deleted=1` and reading it again with your FAST_FORWARD cursor.  Use a STATIC cursor instead, which will iterate a copy of the data, and avoid mutating the data structure you are traversing.

```
DECLARE st CURSOR LOCAL STATIC FOR . . .
```

Comment: And add IsDeleted = 0 to the query that populates the cursor. Or IsDeleted IS NULL or <> 1 or whatever logic you need.

Comment: Beautiful - that worked!

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes that is going to be part of the finished product. I had added the Deleted and CustomerID columns to SearchTables after some data had already been added. I just wanted to get rid of those tables first. The finished version will go into an Agent job.

Answer (score 9):

You want `WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0` which means continue unless something isn't right.

Using `<> -1` means it will continue even if the row fetched was missing, or it's not performing a fetch operation, making it infinite unless you get `-1` as a return value, since there are [4 return values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fetch-status-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for `@@FETCH_STATUS`.

```
 0  The FETCH statement was successful.
-1  The FETCH statement failed or the row was beyond the result set.
-2  The row fetched is missing.
-9  The cursor is not performing a fetch operation
```

.